# 'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp4

I have to convert a .TS file to MP4 File and for that I am using subprocess to convert it.
for this I have written a python file.

```
import subprocess
infile = 'vidl.ts'
subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', infile, 'out.mp4'])
```

I have also added ffmpeg to environment variables path.
also when I type `ffmpeg` in cmd it shows the following

[image]

when I try to run the python file it shows me the error ->

```
'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

can Anyone help me out to where I am missing anything.

Comment: Somehow the `PATH` which is visible to Python is incorrect. Please [edit] to show us how you run Python and what the correct `PATH` looks like (and also, Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors))

Answer (score 0):

As @tripleee noted in the comment, you need to look into your system PATH setting. If you'd like to try an easier fix, you can try my [`ffmpeg-downloader`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpeg-downloader) package.

Two lines of commands in command window (then close and reopen the python window) should do the job for you:

```
pip install ffmpeg-downloader

ffdl install --add-path
```

The `--add-path` argument adds its FFmpeg directory to your Per-User PATH.